# How to rewrite a target only for a root path in ingress rules?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I need to rewrite the target only for the root path, but all others paths must work normally.

I tried the following rules, but it doesn't redirect to /somePath. Instead, it goes to the normal root.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-test-web-app-other
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - test.example.com
      secretName: tls-example
  rules:
    - host: test.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: webapp
                port:
                  name: http
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-test-web-app-root
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /somePath
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: "example.com"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - test.example.com
      secretName: tls-example
  rules:
    - host: test.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Exact
            backend:
              service:
                name: webapp
                port:
                  name: http
---
```

If I try `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"` with `path: "/(.+)"` for ingress-test-web-app-other, I get 404 on opening root path.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

If your application was listening on /somePath, in other words if it had its root path at /somePath
rather than at /, all requests sent to / would be redirected to /somePath. Check the example [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#app-root).

As you can see [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#deployment):

> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root annotation defines the
> Application Root that the Controller must redirect if it's in '/'
> context.

And use the above annotation and below examples, have a try and post the errors if you get any.

As per [ingress doc](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#app-root) , Create an Ingress rule with an app-root annotation as below :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /app1
  name: approot
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: approot.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: http-svc
            port: 
              number: 80
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear. 
I have a domain like www.example.com. There is a page www.example.com/test on it.
And I need to add a subdomain like: test.example.com that will be linked to this path, but all other relative paths to assets have to be linked to the main service. So for instance, a path like test.example.com/image/pic.jpg should not follow www.example.com/test/image/pic.jpg, instead, it should be linked to  www.example.com/image/pic.jpg.